# SQL Server Error Message: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: sql-server

I have having issues with this code giving me the above error.  Do you guys have any thoughts on what is wrong with my code.  It will run sometimes and then sometimes I get this Error?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [Mission_Name]
    ,MR.[completed_at]
    ,C.[CustomerNum]
    ,[CustomerName]
    ,[TaskTitle]
    ,[short_str]
    ,[filepicker]
    ,[first_name]
    ,[last_name]
    ,[TeamName]
    ,[SalespersonName]

    FROM 
    [PWSETL].[GSC].[MISSION_RESPONSES] AS MR INNER JOIN
    [PWSETL].[GSC].[MISSIONS] AS M ON MR.[SITE] = M.[SITE] AND MR.[Mission_ID] = M.[Mission_ID] INNER JOIN
    [PWSETL].[GSC].[PLACES] AS P ON MR.[SITE] = P.[SITE] AND MR.[Place_ID] = P.[Place_ID] INNER JOIN
    [PWSETL].[odm].[V_Customers] AS C ON C.[SITE] = P.[SITE] AND C.[CustomerNum] = P.[custom_place_id] INNER JOIN
    [PWSETL].[GSC].[TASK_RESPONSES] AS TR ON MR.[Mission_Responses_ID] = TR.[mission_response_id] AND MR.[SITE] = TR.[SITE] INNER JOIN
    [PWSETL].[GSC].[TASKS] AS T ON TR.[SITE] = T.[SITE] AND TR.[task_id] = T.[Task_ID] INNER JOIN
    [PWSETL].[GSC].[USERS] AS U ON U.[Site] = MR.[Site] AND U.[User_ID] = MR.[User_ID] INNER JOIN
    [PWSETL].[odm].[Salesperson] AS S ON S.[Site] = C.[Site] AND S.[CustomerNum] = C.[CustomerNum]

    WHERE 
    [Mission_Name] LIKE 'DIAGEO Q3 GM MERCHANDISER MISSION%'
    AND MR.[state] = 'COMPLETED'
```

Comment: It is probably one of the joins or the state?  Is that text or an ID?

Break apart your query add add each join one at a time till you get the error and you can determine what join is causing the error

Comment: Thanks, Looks like there was an issues with a Join.  I had an inner join when I should have had a Left Outer Join.

Comment: A left join instead of an inner join? How would that solve this error? My guess is that the problem is the join to your Customers view. Where you join CustomerNum to custom_place_id.

Comment: If the join change fixed it it could be a data issue (if your columns are not all typed to int correctly.

Comment: This might be easier if you told us which of these columns is the bigint column.